# Will it be considered bad practice, using contexProvider without a consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

Would it be considered bad practice, using contextProvider without a consumer. Like I did below. I found out it worked just fine. Not exactly sure if it's the right way.

```
// context
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { storeProducts, detailProduct } from './assets/data'

const ProductContext = React.createContext()

const ProductProvider = (props) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(storeProducts);
  const [productDetails, setProductDetails] = useState(detailProduct)
  console.log(products)
  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider value={{
      products,
      productDetails

    }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  )
}
const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;
export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer, ProductContext }

/// Context usage

import { ProductContext } from './context'
export default function ProductList() {
  const appContext = useContext(ProductContext)
  const { products } = appContext

  console.log(appContext)
  return (
    <div className="py-5">
      <div className="container">
        <Title name="Product" title="Store"></Title>
        <div className="row">
          {/* <ProductConsumer>
            {(product) => <{product}}
          </ProductConsumer> */}
          {products.map(p => {
            return <h1>{p.title}</h1>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It works just fine, just wanted to know it this could have side effects problems down the line.Or if it is outright discouraged and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike class components, in functional components there is a different way to make use of context value with `useContext` hook and is an alternative to writing a `Consumer` and then using the render prop pattern.

```
export default function ProductList() {
  const appContext = useContext(ProductContext)
  const { products } = appContext

  console.log(appContext)
  return (
    <div className="py-5">
      <div className="container">
        <Title name="Product" title="Store"></Title>
        <div className="row">
          {products.map(p => {
            return <h1>{p.title}</h1>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So, not defining a consumer doesn't mean you don't have a consumer of the context value

Comment: That makes sense, so basically using the `useContext` hook is alternative to defining a consumer?. I seem to like the pattern with `useContext, hope there aren't any drawbacks?. Thanks.

Comment: @johnajiboye, no there arent any drawbacks to it and in  fact its a recommended way to use context within functional component.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like something bad you are doing -

Following is the useContext way of consuming the values -

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

// ...

function Display() {
  const value = useContext(NumberContext);
  return <div>The answer is {value}.</div>;
}
```

which seems like the way you are doing it.

"The only thing you want to watch out for is that you have to pass the whole context object to useContext – not just the consumer! React will warn you if you forget, but try to rememeber, eh?" - is the only difference between `useContext` hook and `Comsumer`.

For more details you can read about it -

https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/